# Aggregate method in MongoDB Compass?

Tags: mongodb, aggregate, mongodb-compass

as stated in the title i'm having some problems querying from MongoDB Compass using the aggregate methhod. I have a collection of documents in this form:

```
{"Array":[{"field":"val","field2":"val2"},{"field":"val","field2":"val2"},{"field":"val","field2":"val2"},{"field":"val","field2":"val2"},{"field":"val","field2":"val2"},...]}
```

using mongo shell or Studio 3T software I query it with aggregate method, follows an example:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
     { $match: {"Array.field": "val"}}, 
     { $unwind: "$Array"},
     { $match: {"Array.field": "val"}},
     { $group: {_id: null, count: {$sum:NumberInt(1)}, Array: {$push: "$Array"}}},
     { $project: {"N. Hits": "$count", Array:1}}
])
```

where I look for elements of Array who has field's value = "val" and count them. This works perfectly, but I don't know how to do the same in MongoDB Compass
[image]

in the query bar I have 'filter', 'project' and 'sort' and I can do usual queries, but i don't know how to use aggregate method.
Thanks

Comment: There is no aggregation support in compass. Use the mongo shell as compass is just an "explorer".

Comment: If you do not like mongo shell, then take a look into https://robomongo.org/ . I'm using Robo 3T, I found that it's very useful for prototyping/experimentation.

Comment: i'm using Studio 3T aswell, and it's really good, but i wanted to try Compass cause it provides more stats for queries (i'm doing a university research on mongoDB performance)

Comment: I'd suggest trying Compass 1.14 (currently beta) which includes an [Aggregation Pipeline Builder](https://docs.mongodb.com/compass/beta/aggregation-pipeline-builder/).

Comment: @Stennie thanks! I'll check it!

Answer (score 6):

You are looking at the **Documents** tab which is restricted for querying documents.

Take a look in the second tab called **Aggregations** where you can do your aggregation pipelines, as usual.

For further information please visit the [Aggregation Pipeline Builder](https://docs.mongodb.com/compass/master/aggregation-pipeline-builder/) documentation.

Comment: Why is this answer down voted? As Stennie commented above this is available in version 1.14.

Comment: The Aggregation Pipeline Builder is ok, but I don't see how to really run it after I'm done building. I can't believe the only way is to copy it to the shell or create a view from it?!